# Coupon displayed after user uses Addthis

Tags: php, javascript, html, addthis

I see addthis has some sample code that may help: http://www.addthis.com/help/client-api#events

In my registration form, I want to display a coupon code in an input text field IF they share my site.  Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the HTML, give your input field an id so you can reference it later:

```
<input type="text" id="coupon-code" value="">
```

Then, here's the addthis listener:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.share', function(evt) {
        // Show coupon code
        document.getElementById('coupon-code').value = "CODE12345";
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Correct.  I'm bad with javascript.  How do I make that listener show the coupon code in the value field <input type="text" value="" />

Comment: For others who may encounter problems: place the script at the bottom of the addthis button section.